# Apache htaccess rule to obfuscate a directory name?

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess

How can I hide the true name of a directory using a `.htaccess` file and only allow access to it under a different path?

Yes, this can be achieved by renaming the admin directory to something else, but using `.htaccess` would be much faster to do for multiple sites and avoids needing to change the script's configuration.

Example - default behavior:

- `http://example.com/admin` --> `/www/admin/index.php`
- `http://example.com/admin/test.php` --> `/www/admin/test.php`
- `http://example.com/MySecretPath` --> *page not found*
- `http://example.com/MySecretPath/test.php` --> *page not found*

Example - with the new configuration:

- `http://example.com/admin` --> ***page not found***
- `http://example.com/admin/test.php` --> ***page not found***
- `http://example.com/MySecretPath` --> **`/www/admin/index.php`**
- `http://example.com/MySecretPath/test.php` --> **`/www/admin/test.php`**

I know how to redirect a fake path to the directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^MySecretPath$ admin/ [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^MySecretPath/(.*)$ admin/$1 [L,QSA]
# all remaining requests - sent to the script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But how do I make it so that the `admin/` directory (which exists) is treated by Apache as if it does not exist?

I also tried adding these rules as a workaround (either above or below the first rules):

```
RewriteRule ^admin$ i-hope-this-path-doesnt-exist [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ i-hope-this-path-doesnt-exist [L,QSA]
```

But it affected the `MySecretPath` redirects as well. On top of that, `http://example.com/admin` got rewritten as `http://example.com/admin/` (forward slash added), which is a different behavior than going to a non-existent path.

Comment: That is indeed possible with a rewrite rule.  Why don't you show us what you tried that didn't work?

Comment: If you have a .htaccess in the parent directory you should be able to do it with mod_rewrite.

Comment: @JuliePelletier Thanks, I added details about what I tried.